# BTreeMap Mutex key does not live long enough

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, lifetime

I am developing a function that uses a mutex and a `key`, both passed as arguments of the function, and this error keeps happening with `cargo check`.

```
error[E0597]: `key` does not live long enough
  --> engine/src/command.rs:21:13
   |
20 | fn handle_set<'a>(key: String, value: DataType, storage: Arc<Mutex<BTreeMap<&'a str, DataType>>>) -> Response {
   |               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
21 |   let key = key.as_str();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
22 |   storage.lock().unwrap().insert(key, value.clone()).unwrap();
   |   -------------------------------------------------- argument requires that `key` is borrowed for `'a`
...
25 | }
   | - `key` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I have tried changing the lifetimes of all parent functions up to the main function without success.

What am I doing wrong here?

```rust
fn handle_set<'a>(key: String, value: DataType, storage: Arc<Mutex<BTreeMap<&'a str, DataType>>>) -> Response {
  let key = key.as_str();
  storage.lock().unwrap().insert(key, value.clone()).unwrap();

  Response::Ok(value)
}

// Both DataType and Response are custom types in my project
```

I am using Rust 2021 edition.

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Your `BTreeMap` lives past the end of the function, but your borrow on `key` only lasts for the lifetime of the function. Either switch your `BTreeMap` to have `String` keys, or take in  an `&'a str` for your key.

Comment: Thank you so much! I opted for changing the key type to String and this works fine now. However, the lifetime `'a` was already the one used for the keys when they were slices. I must have done something, somewhere that prevented it from working they way I wanted it to.